# How can I find out the file extension of a Safecracker file within matrix?

Tags: matrix, safecracker, extension, safecracker-file

I would like to attach different CSS classes for different types of file within a Matrix field. I have tried:

`<a href="{group_files}{if group_files_file}{group_files_file}{if:else}{group_files_link}{/if}{/group_files}" class="{group_files}{if "{extension}"=="docx"}doc{if:elseif "{extension}"=="doc"}doc{if:elseif "{extension}"=="pdf"}pdf{if:else}txt{/if}{/group_files}" title="{group_files}{group_files_title}{/group_files}">{group_files}{group_files_title}{/group_files}</a>`

But this always defaults to txt. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using either [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) or [Ifelse](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse) instead of the native if/else? It could be an issue of parse order which is messing this up for you.

Low has a very good explanation of [ExpressionEngine Parse Order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Does removing the forced parse help? Change `"{extension}"` to just `extension`.

```
{group_files}
{if extension == "docx"}
    doc
{if:elseif extension == "doc"}
    doc
{if:elseif extension == "pdf"}
    pdf
{if:else}
    txt
{/if}
{/group_files}
```

Or with **IfElse** add-on just add wrapping tag pair:

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}  
  {group_files}
    {if extension == "docx"}
      docx
    {if:elseif extension == "doc"}
      doc
    {if:elseif extension == "pdf"}
      pdf
    {if:else}
      txt
    {/if}
  {/group_files}
{/exp:ifelse}
```